# Comparison between Layout and partial view within Asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Asp.net Mvc4 application which contains 4 modules. I need to add Layouts view (master page) to my project and i have two choices :

1. Adding 5 Layouts with no partial view
2. Adding a unique Layout with 4 partial views

I'd like to know what is the best way between it? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion its better to use 2nd approach. As we know we nowadays heavily uses jquery and want to change view content without having to load whole page.Main reason is partial views are more lightweight than normal views

Sometimes we need to load a partial view , then we can use jQuery to make an AJAX request and render a Partial View . In order to load a partial view with in a div we need to do like as:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
$('#divforpartialView').load('/Customer/_myAction');
</script>
```

And moreover idea behind partial view is it is reusable. You can call action which returns partial view like below

```
<div> @{Html.RenderAction("_Action","Controller");} </div>
```